# How to automate reading excel cells and skip the duplicates?

Tags: excel, cell, worksheet

I'm working on this Excel report. It's a bit hard to explain without attaching an example here. So, I will try to put it in manually...Let's call this worksheet A:

```
ENV    SYSTEM    ACTION     CRQ
--------------------------------
PROD   RAC2       PATCH     12345
DEV    te2ds      STAGE     34672
DEV    te2ds      PATCH     34294
PROD   PRAC5      STAGE     47382
PROD   hq2/DBNAME PATCH     47389

etc....
```

That's just a small piece of the Excel table that I have. 
And there is another worksheet X:

```
SYSTEM   DBNumber
--------------------
RAC2       30
te2ds      10
PRAC5      12
hq2        3 

etc...
```

So, what I'm trying to accomplish is, I want some sort of a code (preferably, excel formula..which I doubt helps much in this case) to automatically 'Go in --> Read the cell from Worksheet A, SYSTEM column --> find that name from Worksheet X --> put the relative number under DBNumber in to a cell under a new Worksheet( or a worksheet that I specify), next to its right SYSTEM name. --> If that SYSTEM name/number was already copied over then skip that cell. 
Does it make sense? Thank for all the inputs! I really need some help on this. :)

Answer (score 2):

Following should work for you :

1. first go through the list of "system" Column in your worksheet A
2. Create a Array of unique system name
3. lookup for the value in Sheet x
4. copy the relative value in Sheet z

You can use the following code :

```
Sub unique()

      Dim systemNameCollection As New Collection
      Dim systemNames() As Variant
      Dim i As Long
      Dim rRng As Range

      'Define the range  and assign Values to Array

      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
      Set rRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
      systemNames() = rRng.Value

      On Error Resume Next

      'Add values in Collection

      For Each a In systemNames
         systemNameCollection.Add a, a
      Next

      'run following code to take the unique value from Sheet1 - Lookup for value in Sheet2 
      'and copy relative number in sheet2 to sheet3

      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Select
      Set rRng = Range("A2", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Select

      For i = 1 To systemNameCollection.Count
          For Each Value In rRng
            If systemNameCollection(i) = Value Then
                Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = systemNameCollection(i)
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Value = Value(1, 2)
                Exit For
            End If
          Next
      Next    
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain this line a bit? "Set rRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))"

Comment: #  this line of code will select your range in sheet 1 .starting from cell A2 till to the last non-empty cell in A column. 

# Range("A65536").End(xLUp) -- will do the trick to find last non-empty cell address in Column A  

# if you know your range..you can always go static while defining range like Range("A2:A10")

Comment: (edit : in your case it will be system column .column B) 
Set rRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2", Range("B65536").End(xlUp))"

Answer (score 0):

Since the only System names that you need numbers for are in SheetX, that's the limiting factor. You can copy the entire System column from SheetX into a new sheet, and then use a VLOOKUP function combined with an IF statement to get the corresponding numbers.

**Example:**

1. Copy SheetX, System column and paste to a new SheetY
2. To the right of SheetY, System column, add another column called Number.
3. Make the info in SheetY a table (assume it's Table1 in this example).
4. For each cell in SheetY, Number column, insert the formula:

*=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Table1[System],SheetA!$B,1,False)),"",VLOOKUP(Table1[System],SheetX!$A:$B,2,False))*

This formula says...

- First see if the System value in SheetY is in the list of SheetA.
- If it is not, then "skip" that cell.
- If it is, then find the corresponding number from SheetX.

Last Step: If you're concerned about having duplicate key-value pairs in SheetY, then do steps 1-4 and then Remove Duplicates on the data in SheetY.